# ASP.NET MVC создание сложного объекта

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте. Задача состоит в следующем. Есть база данных заявок на инвентарь. Заявка содержит дату, и, что самое важное, количество требуемых предметов и комментарий к каждому.

```
public class Request
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Дата")]
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RequestContent> Content { get; set; }
}
```

Это содержание заявки, вот содержание RequestContent:

```
public class RequestContent
{

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int RequestContentType { get; set; }
    public int Request { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Суть в том, что в БД есть таблица с предметами, который пользователь в принципе может заказывать.
Проблема в том, что не совсем понимаю, как в странице Create New сделать так, чтобы программа получала у БД список объектов, которые пользователь может заказать.
Сейчас файл Create.cshrml [выглядит так](https://pastebin.com/JhUQaaVL):

```
@model InventoryApp.Models.Request

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Request</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(?model => model.RequestDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

То есть проблема в том, что я не совсем понимаю, как передавать в представление какие-либо данные из кода. Там есть дефолтный model, но как передавать что-то своё не очень понятно. Контроллер:

```
public class RequestsController : Controller
{
    private RequestDBContext db = new RequestDBContext();

    // GET: Requests
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Requests.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Requests/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Request request = db.Requests.Find(id);
        if (request == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(request);
    }

    // GET: Requests/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Requests/Create
    // Чтобы защититься от атак чрезмерной передачи данных, включите определенные свойства, для которых следует установить привязку. Дополнительные 
    // сведения см. в статье http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,RequestDate")] Request request)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            request.RequestDate = DateTime.Now;
            db.Requests.Add(request);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(request);
    }

    // GET: Requests/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Request request = db.Requests.Find(id);
        if (request == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(request);
    }

    // POST: Requests/Edit/5
    // Чтобы защититься от атак чрезмерной передачи данных, включите определенные свойства, для которых следует установить привязку. Дополнительные 
    // сведения см. в статье http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,RequestDate")] Request request)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(request);
    }

    // GET: Requests/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Request request = db.Requests.Find(id);
        if (request == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(request);
    }

    // POST: Requests/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Request request = db.Requests.Find(id);
        db.Requests.Remove(request);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Контекст базы данных:

```
public class RequestDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RequestContent> RequestsContent { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RequestType> RequestTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем смысл вставлять в вопрос ссылки на код на другом ресурсе? Вставляйте весь необходимый код прямо сюда.

Comment: И не понятна суть вопроса. Вы не знаете, как в БД обратиться? Или что не получается?

Comment: Я не могу вставить код Create.cshtml, так как он неправильно отображается здесь. Суть вопроса в том, что да, я не знаю как обратиться к бд, где это нужно делать и как в файле Create.cshtml получить список доступных предметов.

Comment: Вы же используете ASP.NET MVC, то есть Model-View-Controller. Вы показали Model и View - Осталось добавить Controller и там обращаться в БД. Подробнее [тут](https://www.asp.net/learn)

Comment: Проблема как раз и состоит  в том, что я не знаю, как обратиться к БД и где вообще это делать. То есть как в файле разметки страницы брать данные хоть откуда-то.

Comment: Вам надо матчасть почитать, я же не буду тут целый курс по asp.net вам расписывать. В общих чертах, вам надо написать контроллер и контекст данных (гуглите Entity Framework). Контроллер, используя контекст данных, будет доставать данные из БД, формировать модель и отправлять её в представление.

Comment: Так я читал, у меня всё это и есть. И контроллер, и контекст. Проблема в том, что я именно сам способ отправки каких-либо данных в представление не знаю. Есть дефолтный model, а вот как передать что-либо ещё как-то не могу понять.

Comment: Так вы не показываете ни контекст, ни контроллер, хотя все ваши вопросы и проблемы про контекст и контроллер

Comment: Контекст:
https://pastebin.com/WkLgzf2T
Контроллер:
https://pastebin.com/aNsYBd4M
Уж извините что на пастбин.

Comment: Не надо сюда ссылок (я бы если бы и хотел - не смог бы поглядеть), вставляйте все, что надо, текстом прямо в вопрос, вы же можете его редактировать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передавать данные в `View` через `ViewBag` или `ViewData`

```
// GET: Requests
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Name = "MyName";
    //или
    ViewData["Name"] = "MyName";
    return View(db.Requests.ToList());
}
```

`Create.cshrml`

```
<span>@ViewBag.Name</span>
<span>@ViewData["Name"]</span>
```

Второй способ сделать кастомный `ViewModel` с нужными полями.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name;
    public Request Request;
    //...
}
```

и тогда

```
// GET: Requests
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new MyViewModel { 
        Request = db.Requests.ToList(),
        Name = "MyName",
    });
}
```